# Share accepted answer points

Tags: feature-request

I answered a question today, and a few minutes later, so did a new user (got to review their first post). Since my answer was first, I got the 15 point bonus.

I decided I'd like to pass some of those points to the other answerer (the answers were the same, and his was slightly more detailed). I thought I could manually award a bounty - of course, once I looked, I discovered that wasn't an option. The question is too new, and I was looking to give 5 or 10 of my points, not 50.

Is there any mechanism to allow such a thing?

If not, should there be? There are ways that this could be abused, I suppose.

While I'm 99% sure the answers are "no" and "no", it seemed like it might be worth discussion; I couldn't find an existing question like this (on our meta site, at least).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any mechanism to allow such a thing?

#### No.

For a more established user, the closest option would probably be to look at their other contributions and vote up a good one you hadn't encountered before. Question = 5 rep; Answer = 10 rep.

If you're really bothered by this, leave a comment for the question author asking them to change the accepted answer. Once that is done, you can delete yours if you wish.

> If not, should there be?

#### No.

Goodness knows the bounty system has caused enough edge cases and abuses over the years. You will get precious little support for a new ways to move reputation around, especially really small amounts.

---

Somewhat related:

- [How to split points/Mark two answers as 'accepted'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91491)
- [Allow Accepted Answer recipient to give it away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1768)
- [Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2786)

Comment: I did, indeed, ask the author to make the other answer the selected one (and has already voted it up). Thanks for the answer!